# Unable to format/delete harddrive while installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I have a laptop that I am trying to do a clean instal of windows 7 on, but I am unable to remove the old instalation.

When I boot from USB and get to the "where to you want to install Windows" screen, I am unable to select "Delete" or "Format" on `Disk 0 Partition 2:eMachine`. I am able to select them for the other patitions created, but not for the main partition

I have tried searching for an answer, but I am still unable to solve the problem.

From my searches, it looks like most people have been able to solve it by using the `diskpart` tool to format or change the  disk to active, but it does not work for me.

I get the following message:

`Virtual disk service error:
Format is not allowed on the current boot, system, pagefile, crashdump or hibernation volume.`

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/927520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option A:**

Boot from windows DVD, when prompted with the screen where you can select language press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> from here you should be able to remove the partition using the `diskpart` tool.

1. Type: `diskpart`
2. At the DISKPART prompt, type: `list disk`

Make note of the disk number of the disk from which you want to delete the partition.

3. At the DISKPART prompt, type: `select disk n`

Select the disk `n` from which you want to delete the partition.

4. At the DISKPART prompt, type: `list partition`

Make note of the number of the partition that you want to delete.

5. At the DISKPART prompt, type: `select partition n`

Select the partition `n` that you want to delete.

6. At the DISKPART prompt, type: `delete partition`

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738489)

**Option B:**

If you have the option, boot from an external media (i.e. a USB drive or CD/DVD with a bootable environment) and remove the partition from there, so you can install on the space freed up.

You could use something like [Hirens BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) for this.

Comment: I tried option A, but I get Disk SServie error: The device is in use. I then apply the override parameter, but then I get the same error as in the original post. I am unable to try option B, as I only have one memory pen as of now

Comment: Try disabling hibernation using `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` from a command prompt, then try again. I don't see why you should be unable to delete the partition if you are booting from another disk/media.

Comment: I was unable to run powercfg as I no longer had a C drive, so I restarted the computer for the 4th time, and when I got back into the instal menu I was able to select the drive and format it. I dont know why, but the issue is resolved now. Thanks for your help